# Call CasperJS from a script

Tags: javascript, node.js, phantomjs, command-line-interface, casperjs

I currently run a CasperJS script from **CLI** like so:

```
casperjs --ignore-ssl-errors=true --ssl-protocol=any scrape.js
```

.. but to automate the whole process I need to call it from another script as a module/function and pass parameters (keywords etc). So wondering whats the best way to do it.

Comment: Have you tried to use the [cli](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/cli.html)? "Best" in what way? Without objective requirements, this is purely opinion-based.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it. [Spooky](https://github.com/SpookyJS/SpookyJS)!

```
var spooky = new Spooky({
  casper: {
    //configure casperjs here
  }
}, function (err) {
  // NODE CONTEXT
  console.log('We in the Node context');
  spooky.start('http://www.example.com
  spooky.then(function() {
    // CASPERJS CONTEXT
    console.log('We in the CasperJS context');
    this.emit('consoleWe can also emit events here.');
    this.click('a#somelink  });
  spooky.then(function() {
    // CASPERJS CONTEXT
    var size = this.evaluate(function() {
    // PAGE CONTEXT
    console.log('....'); // DOES NOT GET PRINTED OUT
    __utils__.echo('We in the Page context'); // Gets printed out
    this.capture('screenshot.png');
    var $selectsize = $('select#myselectlist option').size();
      return $selectsize;
    })
  })
```

[source](https://productbuilder.wordpress.com/2014/02/23/screen-scraping-with-spookyjs/)